# Playback issues with recorded script in Katalon Studio

Tags: user-interface, playback, katalon-studio, recorder, katalon-recorder

I am having issues with a simple login script I created. I was able to record the script successfully but having issues during playback. The page is not loading well.

[image: This is the recorded screen (as expected)]

[image: This is what I'm seeing when I play back the script]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some synchronization function calls.

After you navigate to the url do: WebUI.waitForPageLoad(45). I usually give it 45 seconds to time out.

There are a lot more sync calls you can use. This article on [how to use synchronization commands while recording](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/synchronization_commands_recording.html) was very helpful for me.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use different waits based on the element on which you are performing action
Below are different waits in katalon studio.

Wait For Element Present: Wait for the given element to present (appear) within the given time in seconds.

Wait For Element Visible: Wait until the given web element is visible within timeout.

Wait For Alert:             Wait for a browser's alert to present.

Wait for Element Clickable  Wait for the given element to be clickable within the given time in seconds.

But i would like to add one point.
If you want to use Katalon Record and playback for simple scripts i.e less than 10 steps, you can do it.
If you are trying to use for bigger scripts it's problematic. I have mentioned all such points in detail at the below links.

https://youtu.be/LQz_kQlMd5o
https://youtu.be/HwQ6QRQvNEQ